# Enable and disable option in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-settings

I am new to creating `PreferenceActivity`. My question is how to enable and disable option in preference screen by changing other preference?

My **prefs.xml**:

```
<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/units"
    android:entryValues="@array/lunits"
    android:key="listUnits"
    android:summary="Units schosssing"
    android:title="Units" android:defaultValue="C"/>

 <ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/palette"
    android:entryValues="@array/lpalette"
    android:key="listpalette"
    android:summary="Palette schosssing"
    android:title="Palette" 
    android:defaultValue="1"/>
```

In the `listUnits` there are 2 options, Celsius and Fahrenheit, so if user selects Celsius the `listpalette` should get enabled, and if user selects Fahrenheit becomes disabled, how can I do this?

My **settings activity**:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();             
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code may be useful to you. Can take as reference.

First take instance of both of the ListPreference and apply this method.

```
ListPreference mlistUnits, mlistPalette;
mlistUnits= (ListPreference)findPreference("listUnits");
mlistPalette= (ListPreference)findPreference("listpalette");

mlistUnits.setEnable(false);
mlistPalette.setEnabled(true);
```

and use below listner

```
OnPreferenceChangeListener listener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {    
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    // newValue is the value you choose
    return false;
}
};
```

apply listener to ListPreference

```
mlistPalette.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: I get "The method getPreferenceScreen() from the type PreferenceActivity is deprecated"

Comment: make it `mlistUnits= (Preference) findPreference("listUnits");`

Comment: you should not call getPreferenceScreen() in PreferenceActivity as it is Depricated. recommanded approach is to write your code in PreferenceFragment, where you can use findPreference() method easily.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you can set default value for your `listUnits` listpreference to `celcius` or `Fahrenheit` ,according this you can  make enable-disable your second listpreference.

Now when changing your Preference by selecting anyone of them you can follow below procedure.

1) implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in your `MyPreferenceFragment` class and override the method `onSharedPreferenceChanged`

2) Code like below in your method

```
  @Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (key.equals("listUnits")) {
                     final String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
                     Preference Pref_cec=findPreference("listpalette");
        if (value.equals("celcius")) {
                     wallpaperPref_admin.setEnabled(true);
                    }else{
                      wallpaperPref_admin.setEnabled(false);
                    }
             }
      }
```

Hope it will Help. Let me know if anything missing in my post.

Answer (score 0):

As your second list is evaluated on basic of first list, what you may do

1. Look for preference click on the First list, get the value of preference clicked.
2. Using this value simply enable/disable your second list.